# Python Selenium : Capture Chrome Dev Tools Network Request/Response Logs using execute_cdp_cmd()

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-devtools-protocol

How to capture chrome network request/response logs using selenium python execute_cdp_cmd()
Here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

siteURL = "https://www.executeautomation.com/search"

site = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def RequestSent(**sent):
    print("SENT",sent)

def ResponseReceived(**recv):
    print("RECV",recv)

site.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable")
site.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.requestWillBeSent",RequestSent())
site.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.responseReceived",ResponseReceived())

site.get(siteURL)

sleep(20)

site.close()
```

Kindly Help!
To capture chrome network request/response logs using selenium python execute_cdp_cmd()

Answer (score 0):

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58023/devtools/browser/a6d642b0-051e-4dc9-b4af-d1d4a24de3e6
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\openia try\apideneme.py", line 18, in 
site.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable')
TypeError: ChromiumDriver.execute_cdp_cmd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cmd_args'

error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).